# IE wants to download JSON result....MVC3

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

My MVC3 app uploads documents from the user to our server. I am returning a JsonResult to display any errors, if any:

```
  [HttpPost] 
    public JsonResult SaveDocument(DocumentModel model, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
         //my wonderful code
         return Json(new { success = true, message="ok" });

     }
```

Heres how i submit the request:

```
 var isSubmitting = false;
  var addDocumentOptions = {
       beforeSubmit: beforeAddDocumentSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
      success: afterDocumentSubmit  // post-submit callback 
  };
  $('#btnCreateDocument').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#divError').html('');
      if (!isSubmitting) {
          $('#createDocForm').submit();
      }
    });
```

This javascript function runs when the upload is complete:

```
    function afterDocumentSubmit(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        if (responseText.success) {
            //no errors
          } else {
             $('#divError').html('Error: ' + responseText.message);
     }
   }
```

In FF, Chrome etc., my javascript code runs fine, but in IE, the browser wants to download the Json result as text. I get a download/open file dialog box that shouldnt appear. How do i make IE not download my Json result and behave like the other browsers? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that actually handles the submit and starts the Ajax request? And, if you're submitting a form with Ajax, are you [preventing the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) for its [`submit` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591998/ie-tries-to-download-json-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem doing the same in Spring MVC on Java. The problem was that Spring was returning the content-type of the JSON result as `application/json`, which seems to make IE want to download it. You can try changing the content-type to `text/plain`; IE won't prompt you to download the file in this case. I suspect that something similar might be happening here.

You could try:

```
return Json(new { success = true, message = "ok" }, "text/plain");
```

In response to your new problem: the issue is that `responseText` is just a string. What you need to do is to convert it into a Javascript Object. You can do it like this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
if(response.success) {
   ...
}
```

Most browsers support `JSON.parse()`. If you're having issues with non-compliant browsers, you can always use the [JSON Javascript Library](http://json.org/js.html).

Comment: I spoke too soon...Now my Json response is returning false, even though its being set to true. So my div is being loaded, but the responseText.message is 'undefined'

Comment: That's because `responseText` is just text. You'll need to convert it to JSON. Editing my answer.

Comment: This may sound crazy, but im doing this in another area of my app. The only difference is, im uploading a file with an added paramerter of type HttpPostedFileBase. The one that works doesnt have the extra parameter

Comment: Interesting. I'm not too familiar with C# and ASP.NET MVC so I'm not sure of the implications of using `HttpPostedFileBase`. Did you try it with the changes I suggested?

Comment: I did...the app just sat there. So i didnt know what it was doing....plus the json.js file is 19k in size

Comment: You could try logging the resposeText to make sure that the client side code is actually seeing it.

Comment: Setting the response type to text/plain didn't work for me. Using the following worked:

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Add()
{
 var result = /* your result generation code here */;
 return new JsonResult() { Data = result, ContentType = "text/json" };
}

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess: you are using the [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin which enables you to upload files using AJAX and you haven't read the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) which states the following:

> Browsers that support the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 will be able to
>   upload files seamlessly and even get progress updates as the upload
>   proceeds. For older browsers, a fallback technology is used which
>   involves iframes since it is not possible to upload files using the
>   level 1 implmenentation of the XMLHttpRequest object. This is a common
>   fallback technique, but it has inherent limitations. The iframe
>   element is used as the target of the form's submit operation which
>   means that the server response is written to the iframe. This is fine
>   if the response type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work as well if the
>   response type is script or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented using entity references when
>   found in HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of script and JSON responses when using
>   the iframe mode, the Form Plugin allows these responses to be embedded
>   in a textarea element and it is recommended that you do so for these
>   response types when used in conjuction with file uploads and older
>   browsers. Please note, however, that if there is no file input in the
>   form then the request uses normal XHR to submit the form (not an
>   iframe). This puts the burden on your server code to know when to use
>   a textarea and when not to.

Now that you have read it you should take the respective actions if you want your code to work under IE as I have exemplified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428595/29407).

Answer (score 1):

The proper JsonResult return should look like so:

```
[HttpPost] 
public JsonResult SaveDocument(DocumentModel model, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    ...
    return Json(new { success = true, message="ok" }, "application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but now my Json response is returning false, even though its being set to true. So my div is being loaded, but the responseText.message is 'undefined'

Comment: See Darin's answer about trying to upload via Ajax. If you aren't using the plugin, then you cannot upload via Ajax. Plus, I suggest you get super friendly with Chrome Dev tools, Fiddler and Firebug

Comment: this will really enforce json as an application, and therefore IE will download this rather than apply/return it as text.