# jquery.form.js plugin fileupload success callback function doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, callback, jquery-forms-plugin

jquery.form.js plugin fileupload success callback function doesn't work in IE.

fileupload success callback worked in chrome, firefox, safari.

I don't know why "SUCCESS callback function" doesn't work in IE ( IE9, IE8, IE7 also.. )

Here is my code < jQuery Form  Plugin * version: 3.23 (11-DEC-2012) >

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function func_beforeSubmit() {
        }
        function func_success(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
        function func_complete(xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                clearForm       :   true,        // clear all form fields after successful submit         
                resetForm       :   true,        // reset the form after successful submit
                url             :   "url <-- just return text string",
                type            :   'post',
                dataType        :   'text',
                beforeSubmit    :   func_beforeSubmit,
                success         :   func_success,
                complete        :   func_complete
            };

            jQuery('#btn_file_upload_ajax').change(function() { jQuery('#frm_upload_ajax').submit(); });
            jQuery('#frm_upload_ajax').ajaxForm(options);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm_upload_ajax" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="attach_imgfile_ajax" id="btn_file_upload_ajax" ><br>
        <input type="hidden" id="data" name="data"/>
    </form>
    <hr><br>
            <div id="image_upload_preview"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417977/how-do-i-prevent-ie-save-file-dialog-when-using-fileupload-in-asp-net-mvc), which deals with a similar problem.

You're uploading a file with AJAX, which can can cause problems in IE. See [this page of the jquery.form.js documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload), which will almost certainly solve your problem.

In short, you'll need to determine if the browser is using the XMLHttpRequest object, and if it is not, return your result in a <textarea> and set the content-type to text/html to prevent IE from displaying an Open/Save dialog box.